# Muestra con el stock_actual del año 202001, como hago para que me muestre el stock_actual del año 202002 junto con el promedio

Tags: mysql

````
```
````

muestre el stock_actual del año 202002 y no 202001 junto al promedio tal como se muestra en la consulta

```
CREATE DATABASE PRUEBA;
use prueba;
create table consumos(
id_consumos int primary key auto_increment,
annomes varchar(6),
cod_establecimiento varchar(5),
cod_med varchar(5),
consumo int,
stock_actual int
);


insert into consumos values (null,"202001","02630","00091",30,20);
insert into consumos values (null,"202001","02630","41696",80,40);
insert into consumos values (null,"202002","02630","00091",100,80);
insert into consumos values (null,"202002","02630","41696",200,100);
```

esta es la consulta cuando obtengo el promedio me arroja el stock_actual del año 202001 pero quiero obtener el stock del año 202002

```
select annomes,cod_establecimiento,cod_med,avg(consumo),stock_actual
 from consumos group by cod_establecimiento,cod_med;
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], pues al menos yo no entiendo lo que buscas lograr

Comment: ¿Qué esperas obtener a partir de los datos que aportas? ¿Un consumo medio? ¿El stock en cada establemiento? ¿Cómo harías el cálculo manualmente? ¿Necesitas totalizar por mes y año, o por establecimiento? ¿Qué es `cod_med`?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es filtrar la consulta porque lo que hace la consulta es mostrar el promedio(comsumo) de todos los registros en la tabla. Para el Stock es una suma.

=> tu consulta

`select annomes,cod_establecimiento,cod_med,avg(consumo),stock_actual
 from consumos group by cod_establecimiento,cod_med;`

solo necesitas agregarle el "where" y el sum() al stock

=> query corregida

```
select annomes,cod_establecimiento,cod_med,avg(consumo) as promedioConsumo,sum(stock_actual) stock
 from consumos where annomes="202002" group by cod_establecimiento,cod_med;
```

Comment: eso realize pero si lo verificas bien el promedio ya tambien varia solo lo promedia del annomes="200202"

Comment: Ni una de las dos consultas hace lo que se espera, mejor deberías colocar un detalle de como quieres que se muestre tu resultado.

Comment: Roussevel solo aplica un sum() en el stock